# Why doesn't \lstinline work in table column?

Tags: tables, listings

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]TeX}
\lstdefinestyle{listLaTeX}{
  language={[LaTeX]TeX},
  extendedchars=true,
  belowcaptionskip=5pt,
  xleftmargin=0.5cm,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily\bf,
  frame=single,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breakindent=0pt,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{deepblue}\ttfamily,
  identifierstyle=\color{deepred}\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{deepgreen}\ttfamily,
  morekeywords={},
  emphstyle=\color{red},
  emph={},
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false
}
\begin{document}
Test -- \lstinline[style=listLaTeX]!\Huge!!

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.29\linewidth}|p{0.29\linewidth}|p{0.29\linewidth}|}
\hline
1&2&3\\
\lstinline[style=listLaTeX]!\Huge!&2&3\\%This line has an error!!!!
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 19):

The answer by egreg didn't work for me, so her is an example how I do it:

```
    \documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
    \usepackage {listings}
    \usepackage {xcolor}

    % Color scheme: original matlab
    \definecolor{src_none}{HTML}      {555555} % 
    \definecolor{src_comment}{HTML}   {008000} % gruen

    \lstset{language            = Matlab,
            basicstyle          = \color{src_none}\ttfamily\footnotesize,
            stringstyle         = \color{src_comment}}

    \begin{document}
      lorem \lstinline{foo = 'bar';} ipsum.\\
      \begin{tabular}{ll}
        11                        & 12\\
        \lstinline[]$bar = 'foo';$  & 22\\
      \end{tabular}

    \end{document}
```

notice that I've used '$$' instead of brackets '{}' it results in:

[image]

Comment: Using other delimiters (like `!!`) works too.

Answer (score 14):

This has to do with the "look forward" techniques that `\lstinline` has to use for finding the end of its argument; with your input it finds the end of the cell, which is an implicit token used internally by TeX and is not legal in user input.

Protecting the `\lstinline` with braces solves the issue, because the look forward will find the closing brace instead of the illegal token `\endtemplate`:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.29\linewidth}|p{0.29\linewidth}|p{0.29\linewidth}|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3\\
{\lstinline[style=listLaTeX]!\Huge!} & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Uh, oops, yeah I looked to quickly while trying to solve a similar problem, disregard my comment

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `\lstinline{xxx}`, try `\lstinline|xxx|` or `\lstinline$xxx$`.