# Lstings in Longtable

Tags: listings, longtable

I tried using the solution provided here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102122/69378) to fix the lstings look ahead problem with tabular to fix the same problem using longtable, but to know avail.

What do I need to change to make lstings work with longtable, and just for my own information, what is different about how longtable and tabular implement their curly brace searches?  I thought this would have been common because it would have been done at base level of TeX internals as alluded to in the linked answer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

    Test \lstinline{Test}

    And the table:

    \begin{longtable}{l l}
        Test & Test \\
%       Test & \lstinline{Test} \\ % doesn't work
%       Test & {\lstinline{Test}} \\ % doesn't work - solution provided https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102122/69378
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: there is no difference between longtable and tabular `\lstinline` makes a multi-line display so needs to be in a `p` column not a one-line `l` column.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for such a rapid reply, I didn't think there was anything substantially different between `longtable` and `tabular`.  When I change my second column to `p` or `p{2cm}` I still get a screen full of errors about braces and `\cr`

Comment: If you look carefully, the code is of the type `\lstinline!test!`, not with braces.

Comment: @egreg I was hoping that wasn't actually the problem, the code I'm trying to escape has ! points in it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did know that you can't use `\verb{XYZ}` but I figured because `\lstinline{}` (the function I want to use in the table) does use curly braces that relative to the verbatim environment they were being treated differently, or as a special case.

Comment: @EngBIRD I've cleaned out some comments do avoid the thread gettimg too long, but as said earlier should be no difference between longtable and tabular, if you have a version working in tabular but not longtable, please edit the example to show that.